# binding to linq inherited types in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, linq, .net-3.5

I have a Linq-to-SQL data model that includes a type `Party` which is sub classed twice for `Company` and `Individual`. I am trying to bind two repeaters to Linq-to-SQL queries as follows

```
    Dim oComp As IEnumerable(Of Company)
    Dim oInd As IEnumerable(Of Individual)

        oComp = From oP As Company In ERM.Parties _
                 Where TypeOf (oP) Is Company And _
                 oP.Name.StartsWith(sSearchString)

        oInd = From oP As Individual In ERM.Parties _
                Where TypeOf (oP) Is Individual And _
                (oP.FirstName.StartsWith(sSearchString) Or _
                oP.LastName.StartsWith(sSearchString))

        rptIndividuals.DataSource = oInd
        rptCompanies.DataSource = oComp

        rptCompanies.DataBind()
        rptIndividuals.DataBind()
```

when I step through the code `oComp` and `oInd` are `IEnumerable<Company>` and `IEnumerable<Individual>` as expected, but I get the following exception when the first `DataBind` call is reached

> System.MissingMethodException was unhandled by user code
>     Message="Constructor on type 'System.Data.Linq.Provider.DataBindingList`1[[DataModel.Party, DataModel, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]' not found."
>     Source="mscorlib"
>     StackTrace:
>          at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceImpl(BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes)
>          at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes)
>          at System.Data.Linq.Provider.BindingList.Create[T](DataContext context, IEnumerable`1 sequence)
>          at System.Data.Linq.DataQuery`1.GetNewBindingList()
>          at System.Data.Linq.DataQuery`1.System.ComponentModel.IListSource.GetList()
>          at System.Web.UI.DataSourceHelper.GetResolvedDataSource(Object dataSource, String dataMember)
>          at System.Web.UI.WebControls.ReadOnlyDataSource.System.Web.UI.IDataSource.GetView(String viewName)
>          at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Repeater.ConnectToDataSourceView()
>          at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Repeater.GetData()
>          at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Repeater.CreateControlHierarchy(Boolean useDataSource)
>          at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Repeater.OnDataBinding(EventArgs e)
>          at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Repeater.DataBind()
>          at parties.lbHiddenPostback_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in \parties.aspx.vb:line 491
>          at System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton.OnClick(EventArgs e)
>          at System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument)
>          at System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument)
>          at System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument)
>          at System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData)
>          at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>     InnerException:

if I then select everything as parties instead as follows, it all works ok

```
    Dim oComp As IEnumerable(Of Party)
    Dim oInd As IEnumerable(Of Party)


        oComp = From oP In ERM.Parties _
                Where TypeOf (oP) Is Company And _
                CType(oP, Company).Name.StartsWith(sSearchString)

        oInd = From oP In ERM.Parties _
                Where TypeOf (oP) Is Individual And _
                (CType(oP, Individual).FirstName.StartsWith(sSearchString) Or _
                CType(oP, Individual).LastName.StartsWith(sSearchString))

        rptIndividuals.DataSource = oInd
        rptCompanies.DataSource = oComp

        rptCompanies.DataBind()
        rptIndividuals.DataBind()
```

There is nothing in either repeater that relates to the data returned yet, just a label in the item template to show me how many records are returned for each query.

It doesn't make sense to me that I have to bind to the parent type, I will be unable to access the attributes associated with Individual and Company without first casting to this type!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix this by using `.ToArray ()` when you're setting the `DataSource` property of the repeater...

```
rptCompanies.DataSource = oComp.ToArray ()
```

I'm not convinced I know *why* it works - but I tried it and it appears to solve the problem!